# Qual é o tamanho máximo de uma variável do tipo int no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Pretendo fazer um algoritmo que crie números primos, e preciso saber qual é o limite de dígitos que posso ter em uma variável. Se alguém puder me ajudar, muito obrigado

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você consegue obter essa informação através de `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

```js
const maxInteger = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

console.log(`O maior número inteiro é ${maxInteger}`);
```

Tal valor representa o número 2<sup>53</sup>-1. Se precisar de números maiores que esse poderá utilizar o [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), que pode ser arbitrariamente grande, mas cuide com o suporte a ele por parte dos navegadores.

Comment: Como eu posso criar uma variáviel BigInt?

Comment: @XTRADEXTRADE Há um link para a documentação na resposta, lá terá todos os detalhes desse tipo.

Comment: Ah tá agora eu vi, Valeu mano!

Comment: Tá mas olha só eu quero converter um numero 2^777232937 e quero escrever ele em um txt

Comment: E da um erro onde diz que não pode converter um numero do tipo Infinity para BigInt

Comment: @XTRADEXTRADE Você pode tentar fazer 2n**777232937n, se seu computador aguentar...

Comment: 2 elevado a 777232937 é muita coisa, cara...

Comment: Pois é eu sei, mas é possível fazer isso né?

Comment: O Anderson, qual é o motivo de colocar o 'n' no numero ?

Comment: @XTRADEXTRADE Tem isso descrito na documentação também, leia lá.

Answer (score 4):

O maior tamanho de um número inteiro é `9007199254740991`, você pode verificar utilizando `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`